# Why does SQL Server use INDEX SPOOL when there is already a relevant index during FK check?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, foreign-keys, deadlock, sql-execution-plan

I've got two tables in SQL SERVER 2019: `Condition` table with 2 FK on `Reference` table. `Condition` table has appropriate indexes on FK columns. The schema screenshot and SQL script to generate it are given below.

[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STnW8.png)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Condition](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LeftReferenceId] [int] NULL,
    [RightReferenceId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reference](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataType] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47458, 94915, 94916)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47459, 94917, 94918)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47460, 94919, 94920)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47461, 94921, 94922)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47462, 94923, 94924)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47463, 94925, 94926)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47464, 94927, 94928)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47465, 94929, 94930)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47466, 94931, 94932)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47467, 94933, 94934)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47468, 94935, 94936)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47469, 94937, 94938)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47470, 94939, 94940)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47471, 94941, 94942)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47472, 94943, 94944)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47473, 94945, 94946)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47474, 94947, 94948)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Condition] ([Id], [LeftReferenceId], [RightReferenceId]) VALUES (47475, 94949, 94950)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Condition] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94915, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94916, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94917, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94918, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94919, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94920, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94921, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94922, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94923, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94924, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94925, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94926, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94927, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94928, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94929, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94930, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94931, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94932, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94933, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94934, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94935, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94936, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94937, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94938, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94939, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94940, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94941, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94942, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94943, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94944, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94945, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94946, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94947, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94948, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94949, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Reference] ([Id], [DataType]) VALUES (94950, 5)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Reference] OFF
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Condition_LeftReferenceId] ON [dbo].[Condition]
(
    [LeftReferenceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Condition_RightReferenceId] ON [dbo].[Condition]
(
    [RightReferenceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Condition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([LeftReferenceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reference] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Condition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([RightReferenceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reference] ([Id])
GO
```

I've got 3 transactions running in parallel:

**Transaction 1**

```
begin transaction

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47458;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47459;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47460;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47461;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47462;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47463;

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Reference] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] IN (94915, 94916, 94917, 94918, 94919, 94920, 94921, 94922, 94923, 94924, 94925, 94926)
    OPTION(LOOP JOIN);

rollback;
```

**Transaction 2**

```
begin transaction

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47464;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47465;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47466;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47467;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47468;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47469;
        
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Reference] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] IN (94927, 94928, 94929, 94930, 94931, 94932, 94933, 94934, 94935, 94936, 94937, 94938)
    OPTION(LOOP JOIN);

rollback;
```

**Transaction 3**

```
begin transaction

    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47470;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47471;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47472;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47473;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47474;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Condition] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] = 47475;
    
    DELETE [t1]
    FROM
        [Reference] [t1]
    WHERE
        [t1].[Id] IN (94939, 94940, 94941, 94942, 94943, 94944, 94945, 94946, 94947, 94948, 94949, 94950)
    OPTION(LOOP JOIN);

rollback;
```

Most of the time the execution plan of the last **DELETE ** statement during parallel execution is the following: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1DZB6y2j

But sometimes (it happens quite rarely) the execution plan contains INDEX SPOOL (With exectly the same predicate as was used during INDEX SEEK in the previous execution plan):
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkIz9GJ3i.

**NOTE**: The execution plan above contains additional nested loop join with `WeighEvent` table which can be ignored, because I simplified the actual DB schema for this question and the same issue was reproduced without `WeighEvent` table. I just don't have this execution plan. Guess it won't be a problem.

The INDEX SCAN before INDEX SPOOL in this case causes deadlock during parallel execution of transctions above.

And my question is: Why does it happen and how to avoid this INDEX SPOOL?

I tried WITH(FORCESEEK) option but it didn't help. I don't know but can it be related to the index sort order?

Comment: Please use the site editor to insert links to images or images inline, it copies to permanent SO/SE imgur pages. Make posts self-contained. But also: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Is table cardinality of `[dbo].[Condition]` always `0`  in the execution plans that have the scan + spool? (as they are in the example at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkIz9GJ3i ?)

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry this is my mistake. I've updated the execution plan that doesn't have index spool to have table cardinality 0. The previous one was a little bit wrong. And yes in my particular described case table cardinality of [dbo].[Condition] seems to be 0 at the time of execution the last DELETE statement because all "conditions" are deleted before in the current transaction and in the other two.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can the fact that [dbo].[Condition] table is being cleared during all transactions be the reason for using index spool?

Comment: I don't know. I'd need to play around with some tests. I have a vague thought that maybe the plan is costed so cheaply "as is" that it doesn't even get around to looking at if an index seek is possible